# Google App Script - Create Google Calendar Event without duplicates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am creating a function that creates a calendar event for a row of data when one of the cells is marked with a 'y'.  I have it working but every time it runs it creates duplicate events.  My work around was to add the eventID to the last column of the row so that I could reference it in the IF statement. So that the function would only run if the 'y' is present and the eventID column is blank.

There are 2 problems I am seeing now:

1 - It prints the eventID in only one cell (S2) as opposed to every row in that column
2 - Still creates duplicate calendar events

```
function createCalEvent(e){

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var index = 2;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    for (;index <= lastRow; index++){

      var name = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
      var email = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
      var approval = sheet.getRange(index, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
      var startDate = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
      var startTime = sheet.getRange(index, 6, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
      var endTime = sheet.getRange(index, 7, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
    
      
      

      if (approval == 'y' && eventId == null) 
    {
      var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent("" + name + " - Time off - from " + startTime + " to " + endTime + "", startDate).addGuest(email);
      var eventId = event.getId();
      sheet.getRange(index, 19, 1, 1).setValue(eventId) 


      
    }
```

Comment: In your script, `eventId` is not declared. But, you say `1 - It prints the eventID in only one cell (S2) as opposed to every row in that column 2 - Still creates duplicate calendar events`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. How about this? First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue and your goal.

Comment: This part doesn't declare the eventId?: var eventId = event.getId();

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your reply of `This part doesn't declare the eventId?: var eventId = event.getId();`, in your script, `if (approval == 'y' && eventId == null)` is used before `var eventId = event.getId();`. I think that in this case, it is required to declare `eventId`. How about this?

Comment: I declared the event and also changed the If statement slightly and now it works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    function createCalEvent(e){

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var index = 2;
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

     for (;index <= lastRow; index++){

     var name = sheet.getRange(index, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var email = sheet.getRange(index, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
     var approval = sheet.getRange(index, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
     var startDate = sheet.getRange(index, 4, 1, 1).getValue();
     var startTime = sheet.getRange(index, 6, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
     var endTime = sheet.getRange(index, 7, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
     var eventId = sheet.getRange(index, 19, 1, 1).getValue();
  
  

     if (approval == 'y' && eventId == "") 
     {
     var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent("" + 
     name + " - Time off from " + startTime + " to " + endTime + "", 
     startDate,{sendInvites: true}).addGuest(email);
     
     var eventId = event.getId();

     sheet.getRange(index, 19, 1, 1).setValue(eventId) 


  
    }}}
```

Comment: The above code was what worked